# How to change replyTo address with macro in Outlook 2007?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using Outlook 2007. Simply I want to write a macro which will delete all recipients and add a new one. Here is my code:

```
Sub replyTo(item As Outlook.MailItem)
    Do While item.ReplyRecipients.Count() > 0
        item.ReplyRecipients.Remove (1)
    Loop
    item.ReplyRecipients.Add ("example@example.com")
    item.ReplyRecipients.ResolveAll
End Sub
```

I also created a rule to run this script. Unfortunately when I receive a mail, replyTo mail is not changing into what I want.

Comment: I don't see anything strange in the code. The only thing I can suggest is to call the Save method after doing changes for the mail item object. Try to handle the NewMailEx event and do the same things, it will allow you to debug the code at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal is not clear but ...

```
Sub replyToExampleImmediately(item As Outlook.mailitem)

' Ignore the sender of the item and reply to "example@example.com"

    Dim replyItem As mailitem
    Set replyItem = item.reply

    replyItem.Recipients.Remove (1)

    replyItem.Recipients.Add ("example@example.com")
    replyItem.Recipients.ResolveAll

    replyItem.Display

ExitRoutine:
    Set replyItem = Nothing

End Sub


Sub replyTosender(item As Outlook.mailitem)

' Reply to the sender of the item and
'  set the replyTo so the sender will reply to "example@example.com"

    Dim replyItem As mailitem
    Set replyItem = item.reply

    replyItem.ReplyRecipients.Add ("example@example.com")
    replyItem.Display

    ' comment out later
    ActiveInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("MessageOptions")

ExitRoutine:
    Set replyItem = Nothing

End Sub

Sub replyTo_test()
' First open a mailitem

Dim curritem As mailitem
Set curritem = ActiveInspector.currentItem

replyToExampleImmediately curritem
replyTosender curritem

End Sub
```